# dynamic reconfigure callback method

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I use a method instead of a function as dynamic reconfigure callback, like with ROS topic callbacks? If not, what's the best way to update my state without using global variables?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64051/dynamic-reconfigure-callback-method/) by [urs.muller](https://answers.ros.org/users/5026/urs.muller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-05-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can. That is the recommended approach.

Here is one way to set it up, [from camera1394](https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/blob/master/src/nodes/driver1394.cpp#L383).

That driver is complicated by having multiple threads. If you want a simpler example, ask. I'm sure we can find one.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1